# Is it possible to overload (shadow) a virtual function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, overloading, virtual-functions

I would like to shadow the virtual function of a base class, and introduce a new virtual function with the same name and same signature, except for the return type.

Something like:

```
struct A {
  virtual int f() = 0;              // Newly introduced method: A::f.
};
struct B: public A {
  int f() final { return 1; }       // Overriding A::f.
};
struct C: public B {
  virtual double f() = 0;           // Newly introduced method C::f. It shadows A::f
};
struct D: public C {
  double f() final { return 2.0; }  // Overriding C::f.
};
```

I expect it to behave the following way:

```
D d;
ASSERT( static_cast<D&>(d).f() == 2.0 );
ASSERT( static_cast<C&>(d).f() == 2.0 );
ASSERT( static_cast<B&>(d).f() == 1 );
ASSERT( static_cast<A&>(d).f() == 1 );
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Any version of the C++ standard is fine.

Comment: in general you can not have functions with same signature with different return types.

Comment: Perhaps it would work if you made the `A::f` function a template, and then specialize it in the child-classes `B` and `D`? It kind of depends on the use-case and the actual problem you need to solve (please always ask about that directly instead).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But even if generated from a template, if two function declarations only differs in return type it will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloading is impossible without changing the function signature (which the return type is not a part of). But thanks to default function arguments, we can have different signatures, but still call with the same number of arguments. Using something like C++20's [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) (easily implementable in any standard though), once could write

```
struct A {
  virtual int f(std::type_identity<int> = {}) = 0;
};
struct B: public A {
  int f(std::type_identity<int> = {}) final { return 1; }
};
struct C: public B {
  virtual double f(std::type_identity<double> = {}) = 0;
};
struct D: public C {
  double f(std::type_identity<double> = {}) final { return 2.0; }
};
```

Each overload is now tagged with its return type, thus giving each a different signature. But the default argument `{}` makes it possible to call them via `f()`. And due to name hiding, there is no conflict in the overload set for an empty argument list.

With those modifications, [your set of assertions now passes](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jx42aopnnyzsMBz8).

Comment: Thanks, this works flawlessly! `std::type_identity` is needed? The code seems to compile even without.

Comment: @Helloer - I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "without". I used it as a universally cheap tag type that can be easily default initialized. If you did `int = {}` and `double = {}` I suppose that may work, but what happens when you deal with types that are expansive to initialize and/or pass by value? The tag always stays cheap.

Comment: Oh, I understand now, you're right. For some weird reason my brain assumed you were using `std::type_identity_t`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't make `C` inherit from `B` directly, but instead introduce `E` that inherits from both `B` and `D`, you can have different `f()`s and disambiguate between them with `static_cast`s.

```
struct A {
  virtual int f() = 0;              // Newly introduced method: A::f.
};

struct B: public A {
  int f() override final { return 1; }       // Overriding A::f.
};

struct C {
  virtual double f() = 0;           // Newly introduced method C::f
};

struct D: public C {
  double f() override final { return 2.0; }  // Overriding C::f.
};

struct E : public B, public D { // inherit from both B and D
};
```

```
int main() {
    E foo;
    std::cout << static_cast<A&>(foo).f() << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << static_cast<B&>(foo).f() << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << static_cast<C&>(foo).f() << '\n'; // 2
    std::cout << static_cast<D&>(foo).f() << '\n'; // 2
}
```